# When is \if executed in a class file

Tags: luatex

I have a custom class file, `myclass.cls`, which contains the following snipped:

```
\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{hintcounter}
\newtotcounter{draftcounter}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\if\ifnum\totvalue{hintcounter}>0 T\else\ifnum\totvalue{draftcounter}>0 T\else F\fi\fi T%
\newwatermark*[allpages,color=red,angle=45,scale=4,xpos=0,ypos=20]{\textbf{DRAFT}}
\fi

\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\stepcounter{hintcounter}\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\draft}[1]{\stepcounter{draftcounter}\textcolor{red}{#1}}
```

In English: if the `\hint` or `\draft` command is used somewhere there should be an overlay over every page.

**Problem:** it never evaluates to true, the if logic is correct if you for example use a hard coded value (>0) instead of `\totvalue{draftcounter}` the watermark is shown on every page. I have also tried to print the value of the counters themselves in the document with `\total{draftcounter}` and they are correct as well. This let me believe the \if is simply not (re-)evaluated.

The document using the custom class is compiled a few times to get the last page, proper table widths ect but it looks like the \if is never re-evaluated in the class file.

What am i doing wrong/when are the `\if` statements executed in a class file?

(Using LuaLatex, but i would prefer general solutions)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `\if` is executed when the class is input, but `\totvalue{...}` is only known after TeX has read in the `.aux` file, which happens much later. You probably want to execute that code like `\AtBeginDocument{\if...\fi}`

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and it seems to work, so is that the general approach used in class files? (when you want commands to be re-evaluated each time) Is it correct to say the class files are processed once, included in the .tex file using them and thus therefore the commands are not re-evaluated when it the document is compiled again? (the knowledge of the inner workings of latex is very limited)

Comment: No, the commands are evaluated each time, but you must ensure that `\totvalue{...}` is known at execution, which in this case it is not, because the value is obtained when the `.aux` file is read in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the class file is executed at the moment it is read, that is, at the beginning of the LaTeX run.

However, your particular code needs the knowledge of `\totvalue{hintcounter}` and `\totvalue{draftcounter}`, which are stored in the `.aux` file during the *preceding* LaTeX run.

So, when reading the class file, LaTeX has no knowledge of what the values are and it uses the value 0 by default.

The `.aux` file is read as part of the `\begin{document}` code and so you want to defer the execution of that part past this point.

LaTeX provides a hook for deferring code in the required fashion: if you do

```
\AtBeginDocument{<code>}
```

then the `<code>` is executed as part of the `\begin{document}` routine, but *after* the `.aux` file has been read.

Solution:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \if\ifnum\totvalue{hintcounter}>0 T%
      \else
        \ifnum\totvalue{draftcounter}>0 T%
        \else F%
        \fi
     \fi T%
     \newwatermark*[allpages,color=red,angle=45,scale=4,xpos=0,ypos=20]{\textbf{DRAFT}}%
  \fi
}
```